# Angular 4 - Moving items from one list to another

Tags: angular

[image]Refer the image as attached here:-

I need to create a form as shown in Image. I have done in VB with list control(cannot recall the exact name). I have to display a list on LFH and with ">>" button, user should be able to move to the list on RHS. What is the appropriate control to for displaying list as shown in form. I also checking on net at the moment.

best regards,
Sidd

Comment: Can't find the attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created the functionality and then used bootstrap classes to display the same. This is pretty easy actually. There are multiple ways to display pop-up in angular too.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

This would help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@swimlane/ngx-dnd](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd) package to make lists (or other html elements) sortable. It has events and data binding support.

Follow the docs in the readme and take a look at the [official page](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-dnd/) with demos and more complex examples.

Comment: I wont be able to use this 3rd party control for now.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the best article using animation for modal dialogue:-

> https://coryrylan.com/blog/build-a-angular-modal-dialog-with-angular-animate

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very simple. Rather looking for VB type controls, I created one and used the same. The solution is very simple. Sometimes switching from one technology to another, it takes some time to arrive to solutions.